# How to make an adjustable font-size based on screen width and content? css

Tags: html, css

I can't find any reference on how to do adjustable font-size depending on screen-width and its content? Tried the following code below but it doesn't work when content change it only works in dynamic screen-width.

```
<div class="sample">
  <span>Sample</span>
  <span>Sample Sample Sample</span>
  <span>Added Added</span>
</div>

.sample {
  height: 50px;
  width: 320px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 6vw;
}
```

**Expected output** should be.
[image]

But the current code looks like below:
[image]

Comment: You cannot base font size on content. CSS knows absolutely nothing about your content with the `:empty` exception.

Comment: @connexo is there a way Sir we can make it as oneline even the content changes by adjusting font-size?

Comment: you can use `rem` and `em`